# Hello World Example For Official Neo4J Driver Is Having A Reference Problem When Calling Session

Tags: c#, neo4j, bolt

Ok,

I'm in C# using .NET Framework 4.7.2. I'm trying to use the Hello World example https://neo4j.com/developer/dotnet/. I've installed the driver w/ "PM Install-Package Neo4j.Driver-4.0" and have a reference in the project for version 4.0.78.1.

For the line

```
using (var session = _driver.Session())
```

I'm getting

> 'IDriver' does not contain a definition for 'Session' and no
>   accessible extension method 'Session' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'IDriver' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

```
using Neo4j.Driver;
using System;
using System.Linq;
namespace ConsoleApp5 {
    public class HelloWorldExample : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly IDriver _driver;

        public HelloWorldExample(string uri, string user, string password)
        {
            _driver = GraphDatabase.Driver(uri, AuthTokens.Basic(user, password));
        }

        public void PrintGreeting(string message)
        {
            using (var session = _driver.Session())
            {
                var greeting = session.WriteTransaction(tx =>
                {
                    var result = tx.Run("CREATE (a:Greeting) " +
                                        "SET a.message = $message " +
                                        "RETURN a.message + ', from node ' + id(a)",
                        new { message });
                    return result.Single()[0].As<string>();
                });
                Console.WriteLine(greeting);
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _driver?.Dispose();
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            using (var greeter = new HelloWorldExample("bolt://localhost:7687", "neo4j", "password"))
            {
                greeter.PrintGreeting("hello, world");
            }
        }
    }    
    }
```

Clearly I'm missing something simple - but after two hours of searching I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Driver version 4, you need to add `Neo4j.Driver.Simple` Nuget package to the project as well. Either via graphic interface, or via command line as `PM> Install-Package Neo4j.Driver.Simple`

According to [Neo4j Driver 4.0](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/dotnet-driver/4.0/html/d4a73f80-d09a-6a10-e6c3-0c0259ce7178.htm) docs, `Session()` is an extension on `IDriver` interface. And as per [Session()](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/dotnet-driver/4.0/html/7c790d57-78fb-e4b3-d3ed-e4bede95f31f.htm) doc, it's from:

> Assembly:  **Neo4j.Driver.Simple** (in Neo4j.Driver.Simple.dll) Version:
>   4.0.2